# To goose takership

Tags: meaning

What does "to goose takership" mean?

I can't seem to find any hints of that through mere googling.

Even "takership" on its own is unclear to me.

Sample context:

> I wouldn't read much into the fact that the new product is winking at
>   us to proceed as they [the company proposing the new product] are
>   simply trying to goose takership and would love to have us join the
>   affiliate marketing program in any guise.

Comment: It means nothing to me, and I'm not aware of any word _takership_. It is either an error, or some kind of joke. It immediately looks like a humorous transposition of _take ownership_, but I don't know why it is _goose takership_ rather then _own takership_.

Comment: I agree with @Colin. Neither the OED nor UrbanDictionary has _takership_ as a word, and the vast majority of Google hits (of which there are only 409) are in compounds like _caretakership_, where it is at least understandable. _Goose_ as a verb means ‘increase, boost, further’, so in the context I would probably read it as something like “they're just trying to get as many people/companies to ‘bite’ as possible”. Definitely a nonstandard phrasing, though.

Comment: That's got to be a mistake.  It is not a real phrase.

Comment: Price-takership is a financial term that sort of means _making trades with negligible effect on the market price_. Could it have been shortened and possibly misused in the quote. I don't see price-takership being sensible and I wonder if _goose_ means to upset or damage. Sounds like it's straight from a marketing dept. (usually a good source of pointless undecipherable twaddle)

Comment: In this context, "goosing" means to "increasing through calculated action: spurring." And "takership" appears to mean something like "participation in a business opportunity" here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a nonexistent phrase.

Comment: Before voting to close, I'd like the OP to provide the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of context, *to goose* = to prod or prompt an entity in order to stimulate demand or action.

*Takership* seems to mean the same thing here as *take-up*, i.e. adoption (of a technology, product, idea etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> I wouldn't read much into the fact that the new product is winking at us to proceed as they [the company proposing the new product] are simply trying to goose takership and would love to have us join the affiliate marketing program in any guise.

Company A is willing to lie, alter or embellish the results of a given study in order to get Company B to accept their product so that Company A can join their marketing program as the person in question from Company B is aware that Company A wants to increase its reputation, name, influence and market power of their new product in the global market.

> **[Price taker](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pricetaker.asp)**: 2. A firm that can alter its rate of production and sales without significantly affecting the market price of its product.
>
> Example: 2. Suppose you sell water, which of course is supplied by millions of other places, including the sky. If you decide to set the price of a gallon of your water at $10, you will likely sell nothing because this commodity is readily available elsewhere for a much cheaper price.

From the example above, the justification of this aspect is put into perspective. Company A wants their product to look more valuable than it really is on the market.

> [Goosing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goosing): (Transitive verb) (American) Give (something) a boost; invigorate; increase.
>
> "The director goosed up the star's grosses by making him funny"

Answer (score -1):

When I was in the navy, many years ago, a "goose-taker" was someone who "takes the goose" (by analogy with a "piss-taker" - q.v. OED). This meant someone who tried to inflate their own importance or get others to big them up. So, I guess, "goosetakership" is the activity of self-aggrandisement. (The quotation given in context seems to be slightly mistaken, in that it makes two words out of "goose" and "takership", and also makes it an infinitive verb rather than a complex noun. But I think it makes sense with my understanding of "goosetakership"?)